# Pause и Resume в Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Сделал пробный проект, в котором идет просто вывод переменной из `List<int>`. При нажатии на кнопку `Button2` переменной `isPaused` приравнивается true. Таким образом проект приостанавливает свою работу. Возник вопрос

Если я делаю количество потоков `4` то разброс данных различается, и я не знаю с какого момента продолжить выполнение цикла. Если бы все шло по порядку я бы мог удалить данные из `list` вплоть до значения переменной `lowestBreakIndex` и снова запустить метод `StartProcess`. **Как сперва приостановить работу, а потом `правильно` продолжить его?**

```
public bool isPaused;
public long lowestBreakIndex;
public List<int> list = new List<int>();


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        list.Add(i);
    Thread th = new Thread(StartProcess);
    th.Start();
}

private void StartProcess()
{
    isPaused = IsTerminated = false;
    isProcessing = true;

    var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };
    ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.ForEach(list, options, (item, state) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        //I swapped these two.
        if (isPaused)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                textBox1.Text += "Пауза";
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            });
            state.Break();
        }
        else if (IsTerminated)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                textBox1.Text += "Терминатор";
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {

                    textBox1.Text += item;
                    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    var lowestBreakIndex = result.LowestBreakIteration;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isPaused = true;
}
```

Comment: Формализуйте проблему, которую должно решать это приложение.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` не предназначен для вашего юзкейса. Почему бы не использовать просто `Task` или явные потоки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть работы `Parallel.ForEach` в том, что его тело выполняется параллельно в разных потоках. Эти потоки планируются операционной системой и могут работать несинхронно. Следовательно, понять какое количество элементов было считано невозможно. Конструкция `Parallel.ForEach` была придумана для других целей.

Вашу задачу можно решить при помощи нескольких объектов `Task`, которые работают с очередью данных `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. Каждый поток выгребает данные из нее параллельно. При остановке задач в очереди останутся элементы, которые еще не были обработаны.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;
    readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    bool isPaused;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button1.Click += Button1OnClick;
        button2.Click += (sender, args) => isPaused = true;
    }

    private void Button1OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        isPaused = false;

        foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 100000))
            queue.Enqueue(item);

        for (var i = 0; i < MaxDegreeOfParallelism; i++)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(StartProcess);
    }

    private void StartProcess()
    {
        while (!isPaused && !queue.IsEmpty)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            int item;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
                textBox1.Invoke(x => x.AppendLine(item.ToString()));
        }

        if (isPaused)
            textBox1.Invoke(x => x.AppendLine("Finished"));
    }
}
```

И для краткости и лаконичности кода:

```
public static class ControlExtentions
{
    public static void Invoke<T>(this T control, Action<T> action) where T : Control
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
            control.Invoke(action, control);
        else
            action(control);
    }

    public static void AppendLine<T>(this T control, string text) where T : TextBoxBase
    {
        control.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: ляпота) сразу чувствуется рука мастера